# Instructions in Chrome Extension using OAuth2 tutorial are not working

Tags: google-oauth

I followed the public tutorial [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tut_oauth) for creating a chrome extension calling Google Identity api to get the Oauth2 token. It is not working. In the Chrome extension loaded into the browser in developer mode, when I click the button in the home page for the extension, it just gets an error

Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.getAuthToken: OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad request' 
at HTMLButtonElement. (chrome-extension://dgpoakddenlpjocgikkadcklmpfmadlh/oauth.js:3:23)

This is most annoying and unhelpful. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in the first part of the tutorial the scopes array is empty.
you can add some scopes, for example `"profile"` and `"email"` and reload the extension.
copy the access token from the console and check it in:
`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=PASTE_ACCESS_TOKEN`